# Confusion about one element in more boost::intrusive containers

Tags: c++, boost, boost-intrusive

I don't quite understand how it is possible that the same elements can appear in different intrusive containers while preserving the performance and memory usage guarantees that the `boost::intrusive` documentation states.

The documentation says that:

> an intrusive container does not store copies of passed objects, but it
>   stores the objects themselves. The additional data needed to insert
>   the object in the container must be provided by the object itself. For
>   example, to insert `MyClass` in an intrusive container that implements a
>   linked list, `MyClass` must contain the needed next and previous
>   pointers:

```
class MyClass
{
   MyClass *next;
   MyClass *previous;
   // ...
};
```

When underlining the differences between STL and boost::intrusive containers, the documentation also says:

> A **non-intrusive** container has some limitations:
>
> An object can only belong to one container: If you want to share an object between two containers, you either have to store multiple
>   copies of those objects or you need to use containers of pointers:
>   `std::list<Object*>`.

Makes sense, an element can't be in two `std::list`s.  Okay. But how can one instance of type `MyClass` be inserted in two different `boost::intrusive::list` 's, for example, considering that such an element can only have one pointer to the next element and one to the previous element. If I am not wrong, this only works if you assume that modifying one container might also modify the other one and vice-versa.

Comment: It has been a while since I thought about this, but I'm pretty sure [`std::list.splice`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice) deprecates intrusive lists

Comment: I totally misread this question the first three times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Boost.Intrusive library doesn't *litterally* ask you to define `prev` and `next` pointers -- in that part of the documentation, the presence of `prev` and `next` pointers is merely a conceptual illustration of how intrusive containers work.

The actual of defining intrusive containers is to include a hook through inheritance or as a member that contains the `prev` and `next` pointers. By including several hooks (tagged with different static types), you can include the same object in several differnet intrusive containers (each tagged with different static types).

See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/intrusive/usage.html to see how the hooks work. See [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6174083/boost-intrusive-multiple-containers) for an example of how to do this with multiple intrusive contianers.

This has some limitations -- you can't include your objects in an arbitrary set of multiple intrusive containers defined at runtime -- you have to know what containers you want to use when you're coding them initially, and build knowledge of each one into your objects.

Comment: Ok. Now it's clear. The thing which I was missing is "by including *several* hooks".

Comment: "The actual of defining intrusive containers is to include a hook through inheritance or as a member that contains the prev and next pointers" - actually you can also implement custom `NodeTraits` and/or `ValueTraits` to deal with whatever legacy linking scheme you wish to support. So you could have a vector of elements and a vector of `pair<index,index>` to define the list container over it. Boost Intrusive is crazy flexible